# How to initiate jquery count when passing div instead of top of page?

Tags: jquery, html, text, opacity, parallax

I'm trying to figure out how to get the following script to start counting the opacity when I pass the surrounding container #box instead of start counting the opacity at the very top of the page.

Anyone has a clue?

Script:

```
function parallaxFade() {
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#boxtext').css({
        'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/100)
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="box">
    <h3 class="boxtext" id="boxtext">Heading</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare the scroll position (ScrollPos here) to the #box position that we get using jQuery [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/). The visual effect won't be remarked here so I kept it for Demo purpose. It's confusing so if you need it to change opacity strictly after the #box container, you change the condition to :

```
if (scrollPos > pos+$('#box').height()) {
```

```js
function parallaxFade(pos) {
    var  opa = $('#boxtext').css('opacity');
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos > pos) {
    $('#boxtext').css({
        'opacity': 1-(scrollPos/(100+pos))
    });
    } else{
    
    $('#boxtext').css({
        'opacity': 1-(1/(100+scrollPos))
    });
    }
    //console.log(opa);
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
var pos = $('#box').position().top;
parallaxFade(pos);
});
```

```css
.box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ipsum">
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<div class="box" id="box">
    <h3 class="boxtext" id="boxtext">Heading</h3>
</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>

</div>
```